# Error in solve.default(R %*% sigma.pi %*% t(R)) :

Tags: r, variables, timeseries

estoy trabajando en una causalidad de granger entre suicidios (observada) y PIB per capita, desempleo, inflación (causa). Son datos por departamento, anuales 2015...2020. Tuve este error:

```
BD_selected <- BD %>% select(Sx, In_diff, Ds, PIB)

select_order_results <- VARselect(BD_selected[, c("Sx", "PIB", "In_diff", "Ds")], lag.max = 10, type = "const")
select_order_results$selection

var_model <- VAR(BD_selected, p = 1, type = "const")
causality_results <- causality(var_model, cause = c("In_diff", "Ds", "PIB"))

Error in solve.default(R %*% sigma.pi %*% t(R)) : 
  sistema es computacionalmente singular: número de condición recíproco = 3.68982e-18

Variables

PIB = PIB percapita
Ds = Desempleo 
In = Inflación
Sx = Suicidios totales
```

Cabe resaltar que los modelos VAR trabajan con variables que sean estacionarias, por eso la variable In tuve que sacarle la diferencia, eliminar una fila y quedar con 197 observaciones. Como el error especifica que hay una multicolinealidad perfecta entre más las variables, no se como arreglar este error. Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda <3

Comment: Con tan pocas variables, es difícil creen que tienes multicolinealidad perfecta, a menos que tenfas variables repetidas. Usa la función `regclass::VIF` luego de aplicar un `lm` para evaluar tus variables de entrada al modelo y hacer una selección adecuada, evitando la multicolinealidad

Comment: Hola aldo, gracias por la ayuda. Me di cuenta que la variable PIB percapita y Desempleo tienen multicolinealidad y lo supe por la función regclass::VIF, corregí el error normalizando las variables. Gracias

Comment: Excelente! Que bueno que te sirvió